# Django: cannot find file using static()

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project `myproj`, with an app `myapp`. In `myproj/myproj`, I have a file `settings.py`, containing the line `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. In `myproj/myapp/static/myapp`, I have a file called `myfile.txt`. In `myproj/myapp`, I have the a file `myscript.py`, containing the lines:

```
from django.templatetags.static import static
fname = static('myapp/myfile.txt')
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        # Do something
```

Here, I get an error in my browser: `No such file or directory: '/static/myapp/myfile.txt'`

However, if I change the code to the following:

```
fname = 'myapp/static/myapp/myfile.txt'
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        # Do something
```

It works fine. Why is the first one not working? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `static()` returns an url to the resource not the path to it.

Comment: It seems like you need to correctly define your STATIC_ROOT within your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

In `open` function, `/static/myapp/myfile.txt` means an absolute path in your environment. `myapp/static/myapp/myfile.txt` is a relative path so it works.

Maybe you want this?

In `settings.py`:

```
# Replace 'your_path` with your actual path
`STATIC_ROOT` = '/your_path/myproj/myapp/static/'
```

In `myscript.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
fname = settings.STATIC_ROOT + 'myapp/myfile.txt'
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        # Do something
```

Ref: 
https://thezebra.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/usage-notes-on-static_root-static_url-media_root-media_url-in-django-v1-3/